# How to use the Zoho Desk Invoke API (Proxy) to call the Zoho Desk Push-Data to Desk (aka Import) endpoint?

Tags: axios, zoho

I am trying to use the [Zoho Desk Invoke API (Proxy)](https://www.zoho.com/desk/extensions/guide/#mp-two-zero-desk-invoke-api) to call the [Zoho Desk Push-Data to Desk (aka Import)](https://www.zoho.com/desk/extensions/guide/#channel-integration-push-data-to-desk) endpoint.

This is what my code looks like:

```TypeScript
// Build the payload
const invokeApiRequestPayload = {
   "securityContext":"edbsnc50b85a3cd964126073f50499ae29a3d6ed3c31123e535e901cdda1b2a312dc0a66c638e2beb2724fffc355faebabf1acd65c3883227c2d329d0c9f62cbbdf26ba4553375b5b11cab90c57590c6b48a3",
   "requestURL":"https://desk.zoho.com.au/api/v1/channels/{{installationId}}/import",
   "headers":{
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
   },
   "postBody":{
      "data":{
         "tickets":[
            {
               "actor":{
                  "email":"test@gmail.com",
                  "name":"Tom Billy",
                  "extId":"NjPk2E6J83g41uDKsD6DznLzz323"
               },
               "subject":"testing new ticket",
               "createdTime":"2022-07-24T01:13:44.419Z",
               "status":"Open",
               "extId":"YCdHTnu93pQbyNoyZzId"
            }
         ],
         "threads":[
            {
               "contentType":"text/html",
               "createdTime":"2022-07-24T01:13:44.419Z",
               "extId":"YGrfU6quGoDESjX5HEZM",
               "extParentId":"YCdHTnu93pQbyNoyZzId",
               "actor":{
                  "extId":"NjPk2E6J83g41uDKsD6DznLzz323",
                  "name":"Tom Billy",
                  "email":"test@gmail.com"
               },
               "canReply":true,
               "content":"testing one two three<br>"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "connectionLinkName":"zohodesk",
   "requestType":"POST",
   "queryParams":{
      "orgId":"7002257443"
   }
};

// Generate the Hmac
const stringToHash = 'requestURL=https://desk.zoho.com.au/api/v1/channels/{{installationId}}/import&requestType=POST&queryParams={"orgId":"7002257443"}&postBody={"data":{"tickets":[{"extId":"YCdHTnu93pQbyNoyZzId","status":"Open","subject":"testing new ticket","createdTime":"2022-07-24T01:13:44.419Z","actor":{"extId":"NjPk2E6J83g41uDKsD6DznLzz323","name":"Tom Billy","email":"test@gmail.com"}}],"threads":[{"extId":"YGrfU6quGoDESjX5HEZM","extParentId":"YCdHTnu93pQbyNoyZzId","actor":{"extId":"NjPk2E6J83g41uDKsD6DznLzz323","name":"Tom Billy","email":"test@gmail.com"},"content":"testing one two three<br>","createdTime":"2022-07-24T01:13:44.419Z","canReply":true,"contentType":"text/html"}]}}&headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}&connectionLinkName=zohodesk';

const hmac = crypto
  .createHmac('sha256', 'mysecret123')
  .update(stringToHash)
  .digest('hex');
// The hmac created from the above code is '2aa21d41882223e2e23ad7004cfdc5a0317db5192fdff84431f0515d4f4e004b'

// Make the Invoke API request using Axios
const axiosOptions = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    hash: hmac,
  },
  params: {
    orgId: '7002257443',
  },
};

return await axios
  .post(
    'https://desk.zoho.com.au/api/v1/invoke',
    invokeApiRequestPayload,
    axiosOptions
  )
  .catch((error) => {
    functions.logger.error(error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
  });
```

But I always get back Error 422 `UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY`:

```JSON
{
   "errorCode":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
   "message":"`Extra query parameter '{\"securityContext\":\"edbsnc50b85a3cd964126073f50499ae29a3d6ed3c31123e535e901cdda1b2a312dc0a66c638e2beb2724fffc355faebabf1acd65c3883227c2d329d0c9f62cbbdf26ba4553375b5b11cab90c57590c6b48a3\",\"requestURL\":\"https://desk.zoho.com.au/api/v1/channels/{{installationId}}/import\",\"requestType\":\"POST\",\"postBody\":{\"data\":{\"tickets\":[{\"extId\":\"YCdHTnu93pQbyNoyZzId\",\"status\":\"Open\",\"subject\":\"testing new ticket\",\"createdTime\":\"2022-07-24T01:13:44.419Z\",\"actor\":{\"extId\":\"NjPk2E6J83g41uDKsD6DznLzz323\",\"name\":\"Tom Billy\",\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\"}}],\"threads\":[{\"extId\":\"YGrfU6quGoDESjX5HEZM\",\"extParentId\":\"YCdHTnu93pQbyNoyZzId\",\"actor\":{\"extId\":\"NjPk2E6J83g41uDKsD6DznLzz323\",\"name\":\"Tom Billy\",\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\"},\"content\":\"testing one two three<br>\",\"createdTime\":\"2022-07-24T01:13:44.419Z\",\"canReply\":true,\"contentType\":\"text/html\"}]}},\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\"},\"queryParams\":{\"orgId\":\"7002257443\"},\"connectionLinkName\":\"zohodesk\"}' is present in the input.`"
}
```

The [Zoho Desk docs](https://desk.zoho.com/DeskAPIDocument#GettingStarted#Errors) have this explanation for the `UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY` error code:

> This errorCode value appears if the input does not fulfil the
> conditions necessary for successfully executing the API.

And looking at the returned error message details it seems to be complaining that I have an "Extra query parameter". That does not make sense to me, because I included it as the payload required by the [Zoho Desk Invoke API (Proxy)](https://www.zoho.com/desk/extensions/guide/#mp-two-zero-desk-invoke-api).

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?